# Impossibly large file in trash that I cannot delete

Tags: finder, macos, trash, monterey

I have a 2019 Intel Macbook Pro on the Monterey 12.1 Beta (21C5039b), and there's a file in my trash that I suspect has been causing me some problems. Its listed size in Finder is 8.32 EB (yes, that's exabytes) and I know that it was not originally that large. It's an application, and the problem appears to be a single file within the package whose apparent size has ballooned to this ridiculous number. I have tried multiple techniques suggested for force deleting files, and all simply return the classic "this file is in use" error. `sudo rm -rf` on the application returns the same error. Does anyone have a more foolproof way to delete a problematic corrupted file?

I have tried `sudo rm -rf`, `sudo find ... -delete`, and checked that the file wasn't locked. I have seen some mention of potentially needing to disable SIP or rebooting into recovery mode, but I have not tried these.

Comment: List all that you have tried so we don’t suggest and then you dismiss.

Comment: @SolarMike I have tried sudo rm -rf, sudo find ... -delete, and checked that the file wasn't locked. I have seen some mention of potentially needing to disable SIP or rebooting into recovery mode, but I have not tried these.

Comment: Have you tried repairing the file structure? If there's directory corruption you don't want to actually delete a container folder mis-represented as containing more than the drive size… in case it takes the rest of the drive with it. You could also try booting in Target Disk mode to another Mac & see if it will delete when it's not booted.

Comment: As Tetsujin says, first thing to check is the filesystem on that volume, e.g. with Disk Utility's First Aid function. It seems unlikely that the file _is_ 8EB long (unless it's a sparse file, or you have an unfeasibly large disk!), so either the Finder is getting confused, or the filesystem is reporting that size. Either could well be caused by some corruption or other errors in the filesystem — and you should try to identify and correct that ASAP before any other files are affected.

Comment: I'm also worried that you're on a beta [of an OS which is now released]. A 'fix' may have been implemented since, but I'd be hesitant to update while the issue is present, without a solid, tested backup & preferably another, belt & braces, done before the beta install. [Note… running beta software on mission-critical devices is never a good idea without a well-planned recovery route.]

Comment: @Tetsujin @gidds Thank you for the notes, I was wondering about this. If Disk Utility and `diskutil verifyVolume` return no problems, would that mean that I should go on to the steps that @raaowx listed in his answer (with a backup of course)?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me, for your description, like the OS access and load in memory some of the files that compounds the `.app`. Against this situation, I would take two approach.

**Approach #1: OS booted normally and logged in:**

1. Find who is accessing that file using `sudo lsof /path/to/the/filename.extension`. After executing this command, you may see some output like:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
filecoord 584 root   42r   REG   1,14        0 4663540 Desktop/foo.txt
```

The downside to `lsof` is that if no process at all is accessing to the file it will show nothing... so alternatively you can execute `sudo fs_usage | grep filename.extension`. As output you may see something like:

```
08:27:29  fsgetpath         /Users/my_name/Desktop/foo.txt 0.000079   filecoordina
08:27:29  stat64            /Users/my_name/Desktop/foo.txt 0.000053   filecoordina
08:27:29  getattrlist       /Users/my_name/Desktop/foo.txt 0.000112   fileprovider
08:27:29  getattrlist       /Users/my_name/Desktop/foo.txt 0.000007   fileprovider
08:27:29  getattrlist       /Users/my_name/Desktop/foo.txt 0.000017   fileprovider
08:27:29  getattrlist       /Users/my_name/Desktop/foo.txt 0.000143   com.apple.Cl
08:27:29  getattrlist       /Users/my_name/Desktop/foo.txt 0.000012   com.apple.Cl
08:27:29  fsgetpath         /Users/my_name/Desktop/foo.txt 0.000052   Finder      
08:27:29  fsgetpath         /Users/my_name/Desktop/foo.txt 0.000004   Finder
```

2. Kill the process that is accessing to the file. For this task, you can use tools like `kill`, `pkill` or the `Activity Monitor`.
3. Delete the file.

**Approach #2: OS booted into recovery mode**

It may happen that you couldn't achieve your purpose with the approach #1. For several reasons like the OS win you the race an a second process re-access the file after you kill the first process or some loop like that. At this point I would do the following:

1. Reboot into [recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314).
2. Mount the volume using the `Disk Utility`.
3. Open the `Terminal`.
4. Delete the file.

This second approach may give you some issues too. In that case, comment those issues so we can think about a new approach with the new information.